# Getting compile error using checkbox shapes in Word (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm getting "Compile Error: Method or data member not found" when trying to check if a shape on my form is a checkbox. This is the code that I'm using:

```
For Each cb In ActiveDocument.Shapes
If cb.Type = msoFormControl Then
  If cb.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
    If cb.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
    Next cb
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & cb.Text, vbNormal)
If Dir(strFolder & cb.Text) = "" Then
    MsgBox "The file '" & checkbox.Caption & "' does not exist in the specified folder. Please try again."
    Exit Sub
End If [...]
```

It is specifically highlighting the second line, FormControlType, in the error. Is there a library I should be referencing?

Comment: You’re attempting to use Excel constants, `xlCheckBox` and `xlOn`, with Word objects. Small wonder Word is confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
  Dim ctrl As ContentControl
  For Each ctrl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If ctrl.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
        If ctrl.Checked = True Then
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure out out!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the checkboxes are on a userform?  If so, you need to loop through the controls on the form and check the typename of each control (i.e.- "CheckBox").

For example:

```
Dim ctrl As control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
```

Etc....

Comment: The first line of code in the question, `For Each cb In ActiveDocument.Shapes`, shows that this has nothing to do with User Forms.

Comment: I believe that what I'm doing is a userform. I am probably looping through the controls in an incorrect way.

Comment: @j-garth That code gives me the same compiler error, for Me.Controls. The following code doesn't give me an error, but it doesn't seem to be looping through the controls:
`Dim ctrl As Control
      For Each ctrl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        If ctrl.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
            If ctrl.Checked = True Then`

Any ideas? I don't understand the difference that my code being for a userform makes.